# Return invalid data in response in Node Js API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I'm trying to update a user and get the updated data in mongo Db using node js. The database data is updating but I'm getting outdated data as the response.

This is my update function

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Content cannot be empty" })
        return
    }

    const id = req.params.id

    studentDB.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body)
        .then(data => {
            if (!data) {
                res.status(404).send({ message: `Cannot update user with ${id}. Maybe user not found!` })
            } else {
                res.send(data)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message || "Some error occured while creating a update method" })
        })
}
```

This is the database user data

```
{
    "_id": "627985c905dcb255365a2c0e",
    "fullName": "Thambili Kankanamlage Ruwan Rohitha",
    "nic": "2021345475655",
    "address": "Old air port road, Nagoda, Kalutara",
    "telephone": "0761234567",
    "email": "ruwan@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0
}
```

When I update any field (example 'nic' as '5433243532324') I get the previous data as a response although the database is updated

Like this **"nic": "2021345475655"**

But I want it like this **"nic": "5433243532324"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass options object with new property to get updated data

`studentDB.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body,{new:true})`